# Usage of CPD(Copy Paste Detector)

Tags: cpd

### test.c

```
void fun(){
    printf("int main char");
}

int main()
{
    printf("int main int");
}
```

->Im giving the command like this `run.sh cpd --minimum-tokens 5 --files /opt/test.c --language c` and the output is as follows :

> Found a 2 line (5 tokens) duplication in the following files: 
>   Starting at line 1 of /opt/test.c
>   Starting at line 5 of /opt/test.c

```
void fun(){
    printf("int main char ");
```

Even if there is no duplication, it is telling the code is duplicated because of minimum tokens.
Is there any way to specify the command without minimum tokens flag.

---

```
void fun(){
    printf("int main int");
}

int main(){
    printf("int main int");
}
```

I specified the command like this "run.sh cpd --minimum-tokens 9 --files /opt/test.c --language c" the output is as follows:

```
Added /opt/test.c <--- (No line duplication reported by tool)
```

This is because I specified the token value greater than the required token value which is 8. In the above case even if there is a duplicated code the tool is not returning any duplicated code.

So how to conclude on Min token size in such scenario in order to get correct duplication of code

Comment: If you look at the "2 line 5 token" clones found, they are actually **void fun(){** and **int main(){**.  It is amazing that you can get an answer this stupid from a clone detection tool. Suggests you should look for a different tool.